# Registry and NetIO conflict - Set Gateway

Tags: windows, winapi, registry, gateway

I would like to address an issue that appears to be known and officially unsolved.

I'm trying to write a sotware to dynamically and fast change the preferred gateway of multiple interfaces. I wanted to do this via the registry. The keys are correctly modified and saved.

The problem arises when, accessing the control panel, the old values are displayed.

Investigating the matter, it emerged that the settings are managed in duplicate. At the same time the registry and the NetIO service. (https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/ip-default-gateway-settings-assigned-incorrectly)

Result, the settings are not taken into account by the system.

The questions that arise spontaneously to me as a programmer, but still self-taught and without great engineering foundations:

Why make a system where the settings are managed by two parallel and independent services, publicly acknowledging that this causes problems, and not solving the issue
How to make the registry settings take effect without restarting the computer?
We can also not give an answer to the first question, but I'm interested in the second...

If there are other practicable strategies to obtain the same result, that's perfectly fine.

Comment: *"I wanted to do this via the registry."* - Unless explicitly stated otherwise, the registry is not a programming interface.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain the concept too explicitly.
I meant that my (C#) app should be able to change these settings via the registry and not via any other API.
If this is not possible then other ways are fine.